# Flexible 3D plotting in Excel - possible solutions

Tags: excel, vba, plot, 3d

I have an Excel sheet that stores information and makes some calculation. I need to display these calculations in a 3D graph - the information is actually a 3D geometry, therefore the very limited built-in Excel functionality will not do the trick. I have seen some attempts to extend the plotting functionality by creating VBA modules but I believe the flexibility and efficiency of this solution is low. I expect that I won't avoid using some external software here.

The quality I need is rather poor, here's an example:

[image: https://cdn.comsol.com/wordpress/2014/10/Model-geometry-of-a-Pratt-truss-bridge.png].

What I would expect from the solution:

1. Interactivity: Scale and rotate with a mouse or buttons - the
   geometry calculations can be done implicitly by the program/module
   or I can do them on my own witch each new view position request.
2. Seamless integration: I would like to avoid having to run completely
   independent 3rd party software to which I would supply some input
   file with Excel-calculated geometry. I would expect a
   degree of automation I can get, for example, with `InternetExplorer` object when
   controlling IE from VBA.
3. Extensibility: at this points I would be fine with being able to
   draw simply a frame structures - but later on I would like to be
   able to add plates, shells and others.
4. Easy implementation: the easier and faster to implement, the better
   -- it's a banal request but I am highlighting it due to its relative importance.

---

What I was thinking about:

- A 3D software like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculix But
  I believe I would run into problems in points 2 and 4 (although from
  what I can read I would have Python to help with the task in the case
  of Calculix).
- Libraries, for example http://matplotlib.org . Here I
  would expect severe problems with point 4.

---

I am leaning towards matplotlib solution, but before I invest significant time in this approach I would like to ask you if there are perhaps better alternatives.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to turn Excel into a 3rd party application like S-Frame, STAAD, SAP 2000, MIDAS, etc.  Might be a time saver to simply buy your own copy of those licensed programs than the amount of time it will take you to develop the same.  Many of those programs work with text input file, which with enough Time you could develop excel to create those text file which would eliminate data entry errors as you move data from excel to the other prg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation based on all the conditions you stipulated is to still use an external app, but control it's data input and launching from Excel's VBA using `Shell`.  The `Shell` command returns the process id of the launched app, so you could potentially even kill it from within Excel (clicking a Refresh button could kill existing instance and launch a new one).